Выдает ошибку telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException:
import telebot
from telebot import types
from telebot import TeleBot
bot = telebot.TeleBot('')
chat_id= 
opros = ('Вопросы: \n'
         '1.Как вас зовут?\n'
         '2.Сколько лет?\n'
         '3.Комплектующие пк/или ноутбука\n'
         '4.Умеете ли устанавливать сборки майнкрафт?\n'
         '5.Сможете ли в любое время помочь?\n'
         '6.Что хорошего умеете?\n')
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Добро пожаловать! Вы попали на бот Окрошки {message.from_user.first_name}')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['info'])
def info(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Как вступить в команду? Нужно ответить на вопросы, чтобы сделать это - пропишите слово Окрошка')
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def zyavka(message):
    try:
        if message.text == "Окрошка":
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, opros)
            bot.forward_message(chat_id, message.chat.id, message.message_id)
    except AttributeError:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Не правильно вели слово')
bot.polling(none_stop=True)

